# exponentiating matrix when values change over time

Tags: r, matrix

I am using a Markov model with matrices programmed in R to solve a health economic problem.

I have a matrix that I would like to exponentiate 200 times. The values within the matrix change over time. For example the value on position x12 is in the first matrix 0.1 in the second 0.2 and in the third 0.3. I do not want to write down 200 matrices but rather one and exponentiate it by 200. For x12: could I use a vector with 200 values and the matrix would use that vector?

For constant values, it is no problem:

```
############### Imatinib Base-line Strategy ##########################
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)

trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(0.9,0.05,0.05)
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.8,0.2)
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=2,ncol=3)

for (i in 1:2){cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <- 
           initial_patient_distribtion%*%(trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd%^%i)}

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  900   50   50
[2,]  810   85  105
```

But if I use the vector, it is not working any more:

```
############### Imatinib Base-line Strategy ##########################
aaa <- c(0.9,0.5)
bbb <- c(0.05, 0.4)
ccc <- c(0.05, 0.1)

trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)

trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa,bbb,ccc)
Error in trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1, ] <- c(aaa, bbb, ccc) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.8,0.2)
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=2,ncol=3)

for (i in 1:2){cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <- 
         initial_patient_distribtion%*%(trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd%^%i)}

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

if I introduce i into the matrix, the results are not correct:

```
############### Imatinib Base-line Strategy ##########################
aaa <- c(0.9,0.5)
bbb <- c(0.05, 0.4)
ccc <- c(0.05, 0.1)

trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)

trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.8,0.2)
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=2,ncol=3)

for (i in 1:2){cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <- 
      initial_patient_distribtion%*%(trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd%^%i)}

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  500  400  100
[2,]  250  520  230
```

How could I solve that problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: There's no way that `mtx^i` is going to work with a varying mtx argument.

Comment: Still have no `initial_patient_distribtion` and cannot see why you think the current output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First comment out this line outside the loop:

```
# trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
```

Then put it inside the loop so it can appropriately access the values and update the prior state value. You will need to handle the first case differently so that indexing on i-1 does not reference 0:

```
 cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[1,] <-initial_patient_distribtion
 for (i in 2:n){ 
        trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
        cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <-
               cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i-1,]%*%    
                                      (trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd)
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost solved my problem, only now I am out of bounds:

Comment: Perhaps use `for(i in 2:length(aaa) )`

Comment: > initial_patient_distribtion <- c (1000,0,0)
> aaa <- c(1,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4)
> bbb <- c(1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
> ccc <- c(1, 0.1,0.1,0.1)
> 
> trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)
> trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
> trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.5,0.5)
> trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)
> 
> 
> cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[1,] <-initial_patient_distribtion

Comment: >  for (i in 2:5){ 
+         trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
+         cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <-
+                cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i-1,]%*%    
+                                       (trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd)
+                  }
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = c(210, 323, 467)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
> 
> cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1000    0    0
[2,]  700  200  100
[3,]  420  310  270

Comment: If you do not post complete updated code, input data, and any error messages in a formatted edit to the current question, there's no way to see what you mean by "not working". It's pretty much impossible to read multi-line code and errors in comments.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved: inserted matrix before the loop

```
initial_patient_distribution <- c (1000,0,0)
aaa <- c(1,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4)
bbb <- c(1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
ccc <- c(1, 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=5,ncol=3)

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[1,] <-initial_patient_distribution
 for (i in 2:5){
 trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)
 trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
 trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.5,0.5)
 trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)
cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <- cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i-    1,]%*%(trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd)
}

cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 1000   0.0   0.0
[2,]  700 200.0 100.0
[3,]  420 310.0 270.0
[4,]  210 323.0 467.0
[5,]   84 266.5 649.5
```